# Confuse with TS and Angular using setTimeoutFunction

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying something very simple with Angular and TS for an Ionic practice. I have a simple button that when clicked changes a text, and then after a few seconds I want that text changed again.

I'm confuse as to why "this.text" wont work depending on how the timeout function is used.

This doesn't work. (this.text is undefined)

```
export class HomePage {
  constructor() { }

  text = "Default";

  onChangeText() {
    this.text = "Changed!";
    setTimeout(
      this.onBackToDefault
      , 2000);
  }

  onBackToDefault() {
    this.text = "Default";
  }
}
```

While this works

```
export class HomePage {
  constructor() { }

  text = "Default";

  onChangeText() {
    this.text = "Changed!";
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.onBackToDefault();
    }
      , 2000);
  }

  onBackToDefault() {
    this.text = "Default";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `this` when used inside a function refers to the function itself. When used in an arrow function, it refers to the outer scope.

In the first example, you are passing in the whole function, whereas you are using an arrow function in the second example.

The first example could also be written in longhand like this:

```
onChangeText() {
  this.text = "Changed!";
  setTimeout(function () {
    this.onBackToDefault();
//       <------ 'this' is scoped to the anonymous function
  }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(
  this.onBackToDefault
, 2000);
```

In this example, the setTimeout method know only elements declared inside it. So, all elements using **this.** will be undefined.

you need to use setTimeout using pharanteses to can use external parameters:

```
setTimeout(() => {    
// do stuff    
}, 2000);
```